# Want to scrape pie chart data. How do I use XPath efficiently?

Tags: html, css, xpath

I want to scrape pie chart data on pages like these https://www.opskrifter.dk/opskrift/104229-bulgur-salat

Its nested inside a table element

The Xpath I tried using on Screaming Frog:

//*[@id="piechart"]/div/div[1]/div/div/table

But no result. How do i do it?

Comment: Why do you think that XPath is the right technology to use here?

Comment: Have you tried to use the selector?

`$('#piechart > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > table')`
or more general `$('#piechart').find('table')`

Comment: @Sam What technology should I use

Comment: @aleberguer Yes I did but no result

Comment: Well, what is your approach? What is your plan to extract the data from this pie chart?

Comment: @Patric my plan was to either use selector and extract data from td attribute or use xpath and extract the table element. But both not working. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should use jQuery to select the td/table and read out the attribute and if you are stuck you can show us the code you have created thus far.

Comment: Is that possible to do for 4000+ pages?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is the simple example to retrieve the data using jquery.

```
$("#piechart table  td").each(function(){console.log($(this).text());});
```

if you want to use the xpath, below is the xpath

```
//div[@id='piechart']//table//td
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure with the xpath? it doesnt work in frog...also is it possible to run the jquery on multiple pages and extract the data? what would you advise to use here?

Comment: Yes, the xpath `//div[@id='piechart']//table//td` is working. Checked form the console and dev tools elements tab.

Comment: what tools and language you are planning to use? Does the pages have unique urls?

Comment: i am using screaming frog but that xpath doesnt return anything. Yes pages have unique urls

Comment: How you are planning to send the urls? You can use python, panda